# Seeing an unexpected error with left_join in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Simple reproducible case, giving an error message that I don't understand:

```
a <- data.frame(this_year = c(1, 2, 3, 4), following_year = c(2, 3, 4, 5))
b <- data.frame(year = c(2, 3, 4, 5), date = as.Date(c("1990-01-01", "1991-01-01", "1992-01-01", "1993-01-01")))
z <- a %>% left_join(b, by = "following_year = year")
```

gives the error:

> Error: `by` can't contain join column `following_year = year` which is
>   missing from LHS

Can anyone explain what the problem is pls?

Also...is it possible to simplify by running something like

```
z <- a %>% left_join(b, by = "(this_year + 1) = year")
```

ie evaluating an expression inside the by = "" section?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct expression would be to quote each column name separated by the `=` within the concatenating function (`c`).  If we pass the whole as a string, it wouldn't evaluate as per the documentation of `?left_join`

> by - To join by different variables on x and y use a named vector. For example, by = c("a" = "b") will match x.a to y.b.

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  left_join(b, by = c("following_year" = "year"))
```

Comment: Thank you. Silly error by me. Oh man...it's been a long day... :-(